# Dropping and populating a big graph in CosmosDB with the Gremlin Python driver hangs

Tags: python, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

I'm dropping and re-creating a big graph with Python on *CosmosDB* based on this [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-db-graph-python-getting-started).
The graph is dropped with `g.V().drop()`, vertexes are created with `g.V().addV...` and edges with `g.V().addE...`.

However when running the procedure multiple times after a variating amount of items or time the adding gets stuck - without result from `client.submitAsync()`.

Comment: Could you please specify how big your graph is?

Comment: Bigger than the usual sample :-) - but still only 600 vertexes + edges. I should put the big in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

When putting a check before `addE()` and `addV()` statements I figured out that the graph was not completely empty after the `drop()`. It seems to take a few seconds.

Hence I put a loop after the `drop()` until the graph is completely empty before I continue with the `add` operations.

```
def drop_graph(client):

    client.submitAsync("g.V().drop()").result()

    remain = None
    while remain != 0:
        callback = client.submitAsync("g.V().count()")
        for result in callback.result():
            previous = remain
            remain = result[0]
            print('remaining nodes {}'.format(remain))
            if remain > 0:
                sleep(1)
            if previous == remain:
                client.submitAsync("g.V().drop()").result()
```

**EDIT:** there seems to be a bug either in the `gremlin.python.driver` or on the backend Gremlin server - in some cases there was no progress in dropping all vertexes. For that I added the kick-start for another `drop()` in case remaining nodes do not decrease.